# Delete Node of HTML by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nodes

Trying to delete specific Node of HTML.

**First HTML:**

There many List in `.widget-content` want to delete all `.list` without First `Li`. Means keep first-child.

```
<div class="wrapper delete">

    <div class="widget-content">
        <ul>
            <li class="lists"> 
                Content
            </li>
            <li class="lists"> <!-- Delete this-->
                Content
            </li>
            <li class="lists"> <!-- Delete this-->
                Content
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Second HTML:**

Want to delete `ul` of `.widget-content ul` if `.wrapper` has class `delete`. Condition need.

```
<div class="wrapper delete">

    <div class="widget-content"> 
        <ul>      <!-- Delete This -->
            <li class="lists">
                Content
            </li>
            <li class="lists">
                Content
            </li>
            <li class="lists">
                Content
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

How to do this by JS/jquery? Fiddle example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.widget-content li').not(':first-child').remove();

    if ($(".wrapper").hasClass('delete')) {
        $('.widget-content ul').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but second one not working, please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/qwc6h1y2/2/

Answer (score 1):

**[slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)** can be used to select elements with a start and end.

```
$('.widget-content li.lists').slice(1).remove();
$('.wrapper.delete ul').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, but second one not working, please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/qwc6h1y2/   - Second HTML has condition.

Comment: @Aabira Updated with this `$('.wrapper.delete ul').remove();`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy not like this, if `.wrapper` has class `.delete` then remove the `UL`

Comment: @Aabira question is not clear... what he has provided is correct.